# Cannot copy-paste from or to the gnome-terminal

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, gnome-terminal, clipboard

I am using Arch linux. However after the recent gnome update, I am not able to copy or paste anything into or from gnome terminal to gui applications like editors or browsers. However I am able to copy and paste within the the terminal like coping and pasting a previous command or output. I am also able to copy paste within GUI applications, for example between an editor and a browser. How ever I am not able to copy paste from the browser to the terminal or from the editor to the terminal and viceversa.

I am sure this is not a keyboard shortcuts issue as Ctrl+ C, Ctrl+ V,Ctrl+  Shift +C, Ctrl+ Shift + V as expected when used within the terminal or among the GUI applications.

I have tried installing clipit, but there is no difference. I am pretty sure I didnt have the issue before.

Comment: Great to know... but I still have no idea what could be wrong... are you using any clipboard tools like clipit? It doesnt make sence that even clipit doest work

Comment: Are you using wayland? I think that copy/paste between Wayland windows and XWayland windows doesn't work (meaning that it has not been implemented yet)

Comment: Yes I am... In non wayland mode, gnome hangs freequently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy/paste between Wayland windows and XWayland windows does not work yet (it has not been implemented).

I can't manage to find any official source on this, but here are a couple of links to posts saying exactly this:

http://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/desktop-linux/49641-gtk-3-18-plans-for-full-wayland-support-a-scenegraph?p=631866#post631866

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/35hz3t/wayland_session_on_gnome_316_part_3_of_wayland/cr4ti4n

**Update**

This feature has been implemented in mutter 3.17.2 (see the [release notes](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-announce-list/2015-May/msg00030.html)).

Comment: that patch seems to be for  clipboard copy-paste (ctrl-v, ctrl-c), not for selection select-paste (mouse buttons).  it seems still broken with mutter 3.20.2